# Confusion on the zig-zag lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am going through Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and trying to wrap my head around the proof of this lemma. We are gifted with the following commutative diagram found on page 116, where each object is a free abelian group.

[image]

In the proof, a cycle $c\in C_n$ is seen as the image under $j$ of some $b\in B_n$. We then take the image of $b$ under $\partial$ back to some $a\in A_{n-1}$, where we finally define $\partial [c] = [a]$.

What I don't understand is this: To show that $a$ is a cycle, we use the fact that $a = \partial b$. Then $a$ is a boundary and thus a cycle. But doesn't this mean that $a$ is homologous to $0 \in A_{n-1}$, making $\partial : H_{n}(C) \to H_{n-1}(A)$ constant and equal to zero?

Comment: Running a computer search on Hatcher's AT for the keywords, "zig", "zag" and "zigzag", "zig-zag" finds only one match and it is not what you're talking about. Could you please reference the page or the name of the theorem that Hatcher actually uses?

Comment: Sorry. This can be found on page 116. He doesn't name the lemma.

Comment: $a$ is the boundary of an element of $B,$ not of $A.$

Comment: So, this doesn't "mean that $a$ is homologous to $0\in A_{n-1}$", and your problem is solved, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now I understand